# In React, how to fix the infinite/loop data passing from the child component to parent react functional component

Tags: reactjs, infinite-loop, react-functional-component

I'm using the `prop` to pass data from the child component to the parent functional component. Both are different js files. Whenever I use `prop` I'm getting the infinite/loop data passing from the child component. How should I resolve this?

This is making my React app unable to load properly and crash. 
Despite using the below react functional component, I'm able to retrieve the data properly without a loop from the React Class component so I assuming is the `CallAPI.js` functional class issue

Child component: DropDownList.js 
Something like below...

```
class DropDownList extends React.Component {

//--body
  render() {

    return (
      <div>
      <CallAPI age={27}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DropDownList;
```

Parent Component: CallAPI.js
Something like below..

```
const CallAPI = () =>{ //create a CallAPI function
  
const [DPID, setText] = useState("");
const [Quote, setText1] = useState("");

let gcmpapi =
  "https://gcm.dellsvc/GCM.Order.API/api/v1/orders/"+ DPID +"/purchase-summary-with-details?countryCode=US"; // declare a variable to store the URL

const [finalprice,setGCMP1] = useState('');
const [totaltax,setGCMP2] = useState('');
const [ShippingAmount,setGCMP3] = useState('');
const [CostPrice,setGCMP4] = useState('');
const [MarginTotal,setGCMP5] = useState('');
const [ListPrice,setGCMP6] = useState('');
const [SellingPrice,setGCMP7] = useState('');
const [DiscountValue,setGCMP8] = useState('');

  const callgcmpapi = () => { //assign a variable for a call function
    Axios.get (gcmpapi).then(
      (response) => { //Success
      console.log(response);
      setGCMP1(response.data.Data.PurchaseSummary.PriceSummary.FinalPrice); // call the value from the multi-dimensional array
      setGCMP2(response.data.Data.PurchaseSummary.PriceSummary.TaxTotal);
      setGCMP3(response.data.Data.PurchaseSummary.PriceSummary.ShippingAmount);
      setGCMP4(response.data.Data.PurchaseSummary.PriceSummary.CostPrice);
      setGCMP5(response.data.Data.PurchaseSummary.PriceSummary.MarginTotal);
      setGCMP6(response.data.Data.PurchaseSummary.PriceSummary.ListPrice);
      setGCMP7(response.data.Data.PurchaseSummary.PriceSummary.SellingPrice);
      setGCMP8(response.data.Data.PurchaseSummary.PriceSummary.DiscountValue);
      })
  };
```

Infinite data loop: [Please see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAwyn.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call APIs in useEffect() hook, your api will be called when the component has mounted:

Ex:

```
useEffect(() => {
  (async() {
    const data = await fetch(...);
    // do something with the data 
  })
}, []) // passing empty dependency for useEffect it should be called one time when component mounted `
```

Comment: Thanks, @Anna, issue is resolved. I was mistaken in calling the `Child component: DropDownList.js` from my parent component return body... For example `return ( <DropDownList />)` Hence, the loop is happening.